# Construct a vector space whose elements are sets

Tags: vector-spaces

I would like to construct a vector space whose elements are convex and closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

A natural idea is as follows.
For any two sets $S_1, S_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, define the addition as
\begin{equation*}
S_1+S_2 \equiv \{s \in \mathbb{R}^n \vert s=s_1+s_2, s_1 \in S_1, s_2 \in S_2\}
\end{equation*}
and the scalar multiplication as
\begin{equation*}
c S_1 \equiv \{s \in \mathbb{R}^n \vert s=c s_1, s_1 \in S_1\}
\end{equation*} where $c \in \mathbb{R}$.
Apparently, the identity element is $\{0\}$. However, $S_1+(-1)\cdot S_1$ is not the empty set. So $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the above operations does not form a vector space. I was wondering whether there is any alternative formulation to construct a vector space for the convex and closed subsets in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Use `\{` and `\}` to get $\{$ and $\}$ in MathJax

Comment: Wouldn't $S+\emptyset=\emptyset$?  Note also that you are not looking for a vector space structure on $\mathbb R^n$ itself, but on the set of convex and closed subsets of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: It should be $S_1, S_2 \subseteq \Bbb R^n$

Comment: @Taladris You are right. So the identity element should be $\{0\}$? But $S_1+(-1)\cdot S_1$ is still not equal to $\{0\}$.

Comment: Yes, but then there is no additive inverse for most sets (since $|S_1+S_2|\ge |S_1|$ if I am not wrong).

Comment: @Taladris - what definition of "$|\ \ |$" are you using? If you mean cardinality, note that the convex subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ all have cardinalities of $0, 1,$ or $\frak c$, the cardinality of the continuum. No other cardinalities are possible, since as soon as a convex set contains two points, it must the contain the entire line segment between them.

Comment: There are ways to turn any set of cardinality $\ge \frak c$ into a real vector space. But this generic statement works exactly because it doesn't care about what the elements of the set are, or any pre-existing structures and relationships built on it. You prove it by building a real vector space of the same cardinality, which means there will be a bijection between the two that you can use to transfer the vector space structure to your set. If you want a vector space that actually cares about the sets being convex and closed, that will be harder.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: yes, $|S|$ is the cardinality of the set $S$. Indeed, except points and the empty set, convex sets have infinite cardinality, but this does not change my argument: most closed convex sets will have no additive inverse for the addition $+$ defined in the question, since $|S_1+S_2|\ge |S_1|>|\{0\}|$ as soon as $S_1$ or $S_2$ has more than one element.

Comment: @Taladris - Sorry, I misunderstood your argument.